# Form submit not working with jQuery Steps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-steps

I'm using jQuery steps plugin to make a quotation form. I want to catch the form answers and then to send it by mail. But actually the `form.submit()` is not working. Here my html

```
<form id="quotation-form" action="index.php?action=sendQuotation">
    <h3>Type de projet</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sélectionnez votre type de projet:*</legend>

        <input id="showcaseBasic" name="project_type" type="radio" required>
        <label for="showcaseBasic">Site vitrine</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="showcaseAppointment" name="project_type" type="radio" required>
        <label for="showcaseAppointment">Site avec réservation de rendez-vous en ligne</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="ecommerce" name="project_type" type="radio" required>
        <label for="ecommerce">Site de e-commerce</label>
        <p>(*) Obligatoire</p>
    </fieldset>

    <h3>Nombre de pages</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sélectionnez le nombre de pages dont vous pensez avoir besoin:*</legend>

        <input id="max5" name="max_page" type="radio" required>
        <label for="max5">1 à 5 pages</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="max10" name="max_page" type="radio" required>
        <label for="max10">6 à 10 pages</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="max15" name="max_page" type="radio" required>
        <label for="max15">11 à 15 pages</label>
        <br/>
        <p>(*) Obligatoire</p>
    </fieldset>

    <h3>Vos coordonnées</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Veuillez renseigner vos coordonnées:*</legend>
        <label for="lastName">Nom </label>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" required>
        <br/>
        <label for="firstName">Prénom </label>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" required>
        <br/>
        <label for="email">Email </label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="mail" required>
        <br/>
        <p>(*) Obligatoire</p>
    </fieldset>

    <h3>Termes et conditions</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <p>Veuillez accepter les conditions de traitement des données*</p>
        <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" required> <label for="acceptTerms">En soumettant ce
            formulaire, j'accepte que les informations saisies soient utilisées uniquement dans le cadre de ma demande
            et de la relation commerciale éthique et personnalisée qui peut en découler.</label>
        <p>(*) Obligatoire</p>
    </fieldset>

</form>>
```

The php action is to send my email.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    var form = $("#quotation-form").show();

    form.steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
// Always allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
            if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
                return true;
            }

// Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
            if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
// To remove error styles
                form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
                form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
            }
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        },

        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return form.valid();


        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
            alert("Je vous remercie de votre confiance. Vous recevrez votre simulation de devis sous 48 heures à l'adresse mail indiquée. Pensez à vérifier votre courrier indésirable.");
            /*
            var radioButtonSelected1 = document.querySelector('input[name=project_type]:checked');

            var radioButtonSelected2 = document.querySelector('input[name=max_page]:checked');

            var contactForm_lastName = document.querySelector('input[name=lastName]');

            var contactForm_firstName = document.querySelector('input[name=firstName]');

            var contactForm_email = document.querySelector('input[name=email]');

            var checkboxSelected = document.querySelector('input[name=acceptTerms]:checked');

            console.log(radioButtonSelected1.id);
            console.log(radioButtonSelected2.id);
            console.log(contactForm_lastName.value);
            console.log(contactForm_firstName.value);
            console.log(contactForm_email.value);
            console.log(checkboxSelected.id);
            */
            var form = $(this);
            form.submit();

        }
    }).validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) {
            element.before(error);
        },


    });
</script>
```

For me, when I call the `form.submit()`, it will play the action from the form, here my `sendQuotation` php action.
Or in reality the input name are sent in the url and the home page is loaded.

What's wrong in my code?

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: try `console.log(form);` to check if `$(this)` pointing to the right element? If not just do `$("#quotation-form").submit();` Let us know if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a POST request (which will preserve any existing query string param parameters on the URL in the `action`) then you need to set `type="POST"` on the form.

If you want to make a GET request, in which the form data is encoded in the URL, **and** include `action=sendQuotation` in that data, then you need to express `action=sendQuotation` as the name and value of a hidden `<input>` and not as part of the `action`.

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting you have to prevent the default form submit

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Add this line before the following line:

```
form.submit();
```